# ODI Groovy obtaining Directory of Physical schema (Path of source file)

Tags: oracle, groovy, java, oracle-data-integrator

I am trying to write a groovy script which obtains the source file location, I already tried using

```
SOurceDataStore.getLogicalSchema().getTechnology().getInternalName()
```

This only returns "FILE" technology that is being used.

If I wanted to obtain this path:

[image]

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method [getSchemaName()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/data-integrator/12.2.1.3/odija/oracle/odi/domain/topology/OdiPhysicalSchema.html#getSchemaName--) of class OdiPhysicalSchema can be used to retrieve the schema (or path for the file technology).

Now it looks like you want to retrieve it from a Datastore so you should first find the model, then the logical schema, then the physical schema linked to it through a specific context. You would need an IOdiContextFinder to get the OdiContext object. The code would be something like this :

```
context = ((IOdiContextFinder)odiInstance.getTransactionalEntityManager().getFinder(OdiContext.class)).findByCode("MY_CONTEXT");
filepath = SOurceDataStore.getModel().getLogicalSchema().getPhysicalSchema(context).getSchemaName();
```